# runweka.bat does not appear to do anything with Weka 3.7.10 on Windows 7

Tags: weka

I installed 32-bit Weka 3.6.10 and 32-bit Weka 3.7.10 on Windows 7.  When I go into the Weka-3-6 folder and type

```
RunWeka
```

at the DOS prompt, the Weka GUI Chooser comes up.  However, when I go into the Weka-3-7 folder and type

```
RunWeka
```

nothing happens - not even any error messages.

Same problem with Weka 3.7.9, 64 bit.  With Weka 3.7.9, 64 bit, when I run

```
RunWeka console
```

I get a console come up with the following.

```
Refreshing GOE props...
---Registering Weka Editors---
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: class weka.cl
assifiers.bayes.BayesianLogisticRegression has interface weka.classifiers.Classi
fier as super class
    java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
    java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    weka.core.ClassDiscovery.find(ClassDiscovery.java:343)
    weka.gui.GenericPropertiesCreator.generateOutputProperties(GenericPropertiesCreator.java:514)
    weka.gui.GenericPropertiesCreator.execute(GenericPropertiesCreator.java:606)
    weka.gui.GenericPropertiesCreator.execute(GenericPropertiesCreator.java:582)
    weka.core.converters.ConverterUtils.initialize(ConverterUtils.java:730)
    weka.core.converters.ConverterUtils.<clinit>(ConverterUtils.java:711)
    java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    weka.core.ClassDiscovery.find(ClassDiscovery.java:343)
    weka.gui.GenericPropertiesCreator.generateOutputProperties(GenericPropertiesCreator.java:514)
    weka.gui.GenericPropertiesCreator.execute(GenericPropertiesCreator.java:606)
    weka.gui.GenericPropertiesCreator.<clinit>(GenericPropertiesCreator.java:149)
    weka.core.WekaPackageManager.refreshGOEProperties(WekaPackageManager.java:880)
    weka.core.WekaPackageManager.loadPackages(WekaPackageManager.java:874) weka.core.WekaPackageManager.loadPackages(WekaPackageManager.java:813)
    weka.gui.GenericObjectEditor.determineClasses(GenericObjectEditor.java:174)
    weka.gui.GenericObjectEditor.<clinit>(GenericObjectEditor.java:248)        weka.gui.GUIChooser.<init>(GUIChooser.java:707)
    weka.gui.GUIChooser.createSingleton(GUIChooser.java:259)        weka.gui.GUIChooser.main(GUIChooser.java:1558)

    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at weka.core.ClassDiscovery.find(ClassDiscovery.java:343)
    at Weka.gui.GenericPropertiesCreator.generateOutputProperties(GenericPropertiesCreator.java:514)
    at weka.gui.GenericPropertiesCreator.execute(GenericPropertiesCreator.java:606)
    at weka.gui.GenericPropertiesCreator.execute(GenericPropertiesCreator.java:582)
    at weka.core.converters.ConverterUtils.initialize(ConverterUtils.java:730)
    at weka.core.converters.ConverterUtils.<clinit>(ConverterUtils.java:711)

    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at weka.core.ClassDiscovery.find(ClassDiscovery.java:343)
    at weka.gui.GenericPropertiesCreator.generateOutputProperties(GenericPropertiesCreator.java:514)
    at weka.gui.GenericPropertiesCreator.execute(GenericPropertiesCreator.java:606)
    at weka.gui.GenericPropertiesCreator.<clinit>(GenericPropertiesCreator.java:149)
    at weka.core.WekaPackageManager.refreshGOEProperties(WekaPackageManager.java:880)
    at weka.core.WekaPackageManager.loadPackages(WekaPackageManager.java:874)
    at weka.core.WekaPackageManager.loadPackages(WekaPackageManager.java:813)
    at weka.gui.GenericObjectEditor.determineClasses(GenericObjectEditor.java:174)
    at weka.gui.GenericObjectEditor.<clinit>(GenericObjectEditor.java:248)        at weka.gui.GUIChooser.<init>(GUIChooser.java:707)
    at weka.gui.GUIChooser.createSingleton(GUIChooser.java:259)        at weka.gui.GUIChooser.main(GUIChooser.java:1558)
C:\Program Files\Weka-3-7>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out.

I had installed an older (3.6) version of Weka.  As a consequence, an older jar file was in my class path.  My solution, on Windows 7, was:
1/ Start
2/ R-click Computer
3/ Properties
4/ Advanced system settings
5/ Environmental Variables
6/ System variables
7/ CLASSPATH: Edit
8/ Remove anything to do with older version of Weka